# Solving the Wave Equation Using Separation of Variables (Displacement on a string)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Consider a semi-infinite string stretched between $2$ fixed points. Let $u(x, t)$ be the displacement of a string, at position $x$ and time $t.$

We describe the wave equation by:
$$u(x, t) = h_1(x − ct) + h_2(x + ct)$$
for arbitrary functions $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z).$

The string is subject to boundary conditions: $$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 ,\: t > 0.$$

The string has an initial displacement $u(x, 0) = f(x), x ∈ (0, 1)$ and is initially at rest.

**Use separation of variables to find the displacement of the string for** $\textbf{t > 0.}$

Using the identity $\sin \theta \cos \phi =\frac{1}{2}(\sin(\theta − \phi) + sin(\theta + \phi))$ and the Sturm Liouville boundary value problem

$X''(x) + λX(x) = 0; X(0) = X(1) = 0$
has eigenvalues $λ_n = n^2π^2$
with corresponding eigenfunctions $X_n(x) = sin (nπx)$.

, rewrite your answer in the same form as
$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}(\overset{ˆ}{f}(x − ct) + \overset{ˆ}{f}(x + ct))$$

I've done the first part of this question which provided me with most of the information here but I really have no idea how to draw all this stuff together. I'm desperate at the moment so any help would be appreciated.

So far this is what I've done:

$$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$$ in $0 < x < 1$ subject to the initial and (homogeneous) Dirichlet boundary conditions given above.

Use separation of variables and let $u = P(t)Q(x)$. The problems for $P$ and $Q$ are second order ODEs:

$$ P''/(c^2 P) = Q''/Q = \lambda$$

Where $\lambda$ is a separation constant. The only functions satisfying $Q(0) = Q(1) = 0$ are

$$ Q_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x), \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots$$

where I have made $|\lambda| = n^2 \pi^2$.

I am seeking solutions $u$ in the most general form

$$ u = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(t) Q_n(x), $$

because there are infinitely many *eigenfunctions* $Q_n$. From the PDE, one has

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (Q_n P''_n - c^2 Q''_n P_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty Q_n [ P''_n + (n \pi c)^2 P_n ] = 0$$

Now, leverage the orthogonality properties of $Q_n$ to find an equation for $P_n(t)$ (in this case is trivial), to be solved with initial conditions
\begin{align} 
& u = 0 \implies P(0) = 0 \\
& u_t = f(x) \implies P'_n(0) = \frac{\int^1_0 Q_n(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}{ \int^1_0 Q^2_n(x) f(x)  }
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The separation of variables solution for $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ has the form
$$
    u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\cos(n\pi ct)+B_n\sin(n\pi ct))\sin(n\pi x).
$$
where the $A_n$ and $B_n$ are determined by the sine series for $u(x,0)$ and $u_t(x,0)$ respectively. 
Then it's a matter of using trig identities to write
$$
        \cos(n\pi ct)\sin(n\pi x)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(n\pi x-n\pi ct)+\sin(n\pi x+n\pi ct)) \\
        \sin(n\pi ct)\sin(n\pi x)=\frac{1}{2}(-\cos(n\pi ct+n\pi x)+\cos(n\pi ct-n\pi x)).
$$
After you substitute these back into the expression for $u(x,t)$, you get what you want.